# Xtabs command error

Tags: r, import

I have recently started learning to use R. I imported a csv data into R and used xtabs with it.

I use the following commands:

```
train.df=read.csv("train.csv")
xtabs( ~class, data=train.df)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~class, data = train.df) : 
  object is not a matrix
```

I tried xtabs command with the dataset given at the bottom of [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/classification-trees/) page and it works fine. I even tried converting my dataset into a matrix using 
as.matrix(train.df)
but this doesnt work either.

Can someone please point out what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: Put the commands and erros in `code blocks`

Comment: `train.df=read.csv("train.txt")`

Comment: `xtabs( ~class, data=train.df)`

Comment: `Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~class, data = train.df) : object is not a matrix`

Comment: We have no idea what `train.csv` looks like. Please tell us by copy+pasting `dput(head(train.df))` into your question or showing us the structure of `train.csv`.